# How to generate reports in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to generate reports in PrimeFaces such as PDF File. I have generated a QR code for a user id and now I want to print user data on PDF with QR code. I am using separate library to generate QR code. Can somebody tell how to implement this?

Comment: [`<p:dataExporter>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml). Click also the other relevant links on the page.

Comment: By using the libraries like itext or apache fop or apache poi we can generate the pdf file in java.

Comment: Google Jasper reports. Create report (using visual designer, easy when you create you report system and basic methods), compile it and download using http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml

Comment: Also you can use  `p:media` for show generated PDF as streamed content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data exporter tag. but remember it will not work with with IBM portal server portlets.

```
<p:commandLink id="pdf" ajax="false"  >  
         <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/pdf.png"/>  
         <f:setPropertyActionListener value="true" target="#{exporterController.customExporter}" />  

         <pe:exporter type="pdf" target="messageTable" fileName="MessagesTable"/>  

     </p:commandLink>
```

Comment: Hello Kavi. I can't seem to find where the #{exporterController.customExporter} comes from. What is the method implementation?

Comment: @Erick This is inbuilt component of primefaces. See http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/exporter/customExporter.jsf;jsessionid=ry3ifuxwxbx20u90jd6xtqr